# Can Swift protocols be defined as dynamic?

Tags: objective-c, swift, typhoon

I've converted [most of my application to Swift](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon-Swift-Example). What's left is a number of Objective-C protocols, and some code that should use Swift idioms in place of Objective-C style.

I've done the assembly of my application using [Typhoon](http://typhoonframework.org/). Now after converting one of the protocols to Swift, I noticed the intializer was no longer dynamic (required by the DI library). So I tried marking it explicitly dynamic, but got the following error:

[image: Protocol can't be dynamic]

Its complaining that the 3rd argument (my Swift protocol) can never participate as part of Objective-C.  This seems like it would be a widespread limitation for Swift/ObjC interoperability. Is the only solution to define the protocol in ObjC and have the Swift classes implement that?

**The following solution did not work:**

```
public protocol WeatherReportDao : NSObjectProtocol { //Extend NSObjectProtocol 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the best work-around is to add the @objc directive to the Swift protocol. Example:

```
@objc public protocol CityDao {

//etc. . . 

}
```

. . to me, this is archaic, as what I'd really like to communicate is that the protocol requires dyanmic dispatch - something that can go beyond Swift-ObjC interoperability.

Still, it works just fine.